# Cannot Allocate Memory while installing laravel in ec2

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, composer-php

I have one project with angular and laravel. It is working in loclahost. I want to deploy it in server. So in my /var/www/html/ I kept my angular files. And in /var/www/html/api I want to keep the laravel files. But laravel is not installing. It's showing the below errors. I increased /etc/php.ini memory limit also. I copied existing laravel file. It's only showing directories rather running the app. From the laravel public folder also it's not running.
Sorry for my poor english. Thanks in advance.

```
mmap() failed: [12] Cannot allocate memory

PHP Fatal error:  Out of memory (allocated 725622784) (tried to allocate 33554440 bytes) in phar:///var/www/html/api/composer.phar/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/RuleSet.php on line 84

Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 725622784) (tried to allocate 33554440 bytes) in phar:///var/www/html/api/composer.phar/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/RuleSet.php on line 84
```

Answer (score -1):

This  doesn't matter on  the  App  Level or your Laravel  you need to allocate your PHP with higher memory limit.

Comment: Okay but from where should I upgrade my php version? /etc/php.ini isn't it?

Comment: no . go on to your php you are using are  you might be using multiple version of php.     default  directory  sometimes via  /etc/php/5.6/php.ini change 5.6  depends on  the  version you are using. eg 7.1 , 7.2 etc

Comment: if you are using fpm  .  look  on the directory php-fpm.conf file .  or  look for pool.d folder then adjust the memory limit via www.conf file

Comment: however if its hardware limitation. you need to upgrade as well

Comment: like  if your resources needs to  use 1GB and ung  RAM  is lower than 1GB . its definitely a hardware fault. upgrade to a higher specs.

Answer (score -2):

What type of instance of you using?
Have you tried with a largest type (e.g. t3.medium instead of t3.micro)?

Comment: Its t2.micro sir. i don't know how change o t3. Can you please elaborate? I'm new to AWS.